# How to properly configure marshalling with Spring WebServiceTemplate

Tags: spring, jaxb, marshalling, spring-ws

I have been trying do figure out how to properly configure the marshalling for the WebServiceTemplate. I am using Spring Web Services just for the WebServiceTemaplate as a client to communicate with a backend I have no control over. The required classes are pre-converted from xsd to POJOs by Jaxb2 and I am using the generated ObjectFactory to properly create the request-object.

My problem is that all the configuration I am doing in my `SsiConfig` for the `Jaxb2Marshaller` class, is not represented in the generated XML. The `DumbEscapeHandler` is not used to escape special characters and the XML declaration is not showing the changed encoding (it is always `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` and I did not find a way to change it). Furthermore, the options `JAXB_FRAGMENT` and `JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` do not change the marshalled result at all.

I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong here but a long debugging session through the Framework classes did not help me figure this out.

This is my `WebServiceTemplate` and `Jaxb2Marshaller` configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SsiClientSecurityConfig.class)
public class SsiConfig
{
    @Bean
    public SsiClient ssiClient(
        @Value("${url}") final String url,
        @Value("${url.alternative}") final String urlAlternative,
        final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller,
        @Autowired final HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender
    )
    {
        final WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();
        template.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        template.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        template.setDefaultUri(url);
        template.setMessageFactory(new DomPoxMessageFactory());
        template.setMessageSender(messageSender);

        return new SsiClient(template, url, urlAlternative);
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller()
    {
        final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("my.interface.package");
        marshaller.setCheckForXmlRootElement(true);
        marshaller.setSupportDtd(true);
        marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(false);
        marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(
            Map.of(
                Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.toString(),
                Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, false,
                Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false,
                "com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler", DumbEscapeHandler.theInstance,
                "com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"
            )
        );
        marshaller.setUnmarshallerProperties(
            Map.of(
                Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.toString()
            )
        );

        return marshaller;
    }
}
```